# wordpress custom post type capability read_(cpt) not available

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom post type "produktionsauftrag" in my functions.php file. For a specific user-role (shop_manager from woocommerce) i need special rights for this custom post type.

The shop_manager should be able to create a post but then not to edit it (just read). When i create my custom post type with its own capability_type i can change the rights but there is no read_cpt option as you can see:

[image]

How can i add a read_auftrags option? My custom post type in functions.php:

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_produktionsauftrag() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Produktionsaufträge.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "Produktionsaufträge", "" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Produktionsauftrag", "" ),
        "menu_name" => __( "Produktionsaufträge", "" ),
        "all_items" => __( "Alle Produktionsaufträge", "" ),
        "add_new" => __( "Produktionsauftrag erstellen", "" ),
        "add_new_item" => __( "Produktionsauftrag erstellen", "" ),
        "edit_item" => __( "Produktionsauftrag anpassen", "" ),
        "new_item" => __( "Neuer Produktionsauftrag", "" ),
        "view_item" => __( "Produktionsauftrag anzeigen", "" ),
        "view_items" => __( "Produktionsaufträge anzeigen", "" ),
        "search_items" => __( "Produktionsauftrag suchen", "" ),
        "not_found" => __( "Keine Produktionsaufträge gefunden", "" ),
        "not_found_in_trash" => __( "Keine Produktionsaufträge gefunden", "" ),
        "items_list" => __( "Produktionsauftragsliste", "" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Produktionsaufträge", "" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => false,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        'capability_type' => 'auftrag',
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "produktionsauftrag", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "author" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "produktionsauftrag", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_produktionsauftrag' );
```

Comment: Read is enabled on all posts by default. Are you having problems with read-access to your posts?

Comment: No, i dont have any problems with reading access to my posts. The problem is that i created a custom post type and one user_role should be able to publish new posts of this post type and read it but not edit it after published. In the plugin user role editor i cant see a capability read_(cpt-name) only read_private_(cpt-name).

Comment: That's because 'read' is a default setting for all posts so you don't have the capability to turn if on & off for custom post types.

Comment: So what i try to do is not possible? What i need is that i can set the rights so that a user can create a post but then he should not be able to change it.

Comment: The read privileges wouldn't have any effect on what you're trying to do - they cannot change anything with just read privileges. It's their edit privileges that you'd need to change.

Comment: When i just set the rights for edit then after i created a post, i cant edit it. Cant even open it. So i think there must be something like a read capability.

Answer (score 1):

The `read` capability isn't a standard capability that you can apply to a CPT, but it looks like you can set it.

The capabilities accepted for a CPT as part of the capabilities array are:

- edit_posts, edit_others_posts, publish_posts, read_private_posts
- and the *meta capabilities*: edit_post, **read_post**, and delete_post

**Meta capabilities** are capabilities a user is granted on a *per-post* basis, and get mapped to the following primitive capabilities:

- read, edit_published_posts, edit_private_posts, create_posts, delete_posts, delete_private_posts, delete_published_posts, delete_others_posts

*Note, the code here was used on questions/answers on wordpress.stackexchange.com, which seems to be in contradiction with the Codex (see below). But if it works for others, its worth trying first!*

**Custom Post Type:**

You can explicitly set the capabilities like this (it might be done automatically when you use `"map_meta_cap" => true`, but its not clear):

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_produktionsauftrag() {

    [...] 

    $args = array(

        [...]

        'capability_type' => 'auftrag',
        "map_meta_cap" => true, /* You need this (which you already had) */

        /* set the capabilities for both plural AND single, e.g. */
        'capabilities' => array(
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_auftrags',
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_auftrags',
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_other_auftrags',
            'delete_posts' => 'delete_auftrags',
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_auftrags',
            'edit_post' => 'edit_auftrag',
            'delete_post' => 'delete_auftrag'
            'read_post' => 'read_auftrag',
        ),
    );

    register_post_type( "produktionsauftrag", $args );
}
    add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_produktionsauftrag' );
```

Then you should add the capabilities to the appropriate user roles. Note that it was mentioned in one of the answers that you need to add capabilities to administrator to be able to edit the posts in the admin.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_produktionsauftrag_caps_role');
function add_produktionsauftrag_caps_role() {

    /* Get the roles you want to add capabilities for, e.g. */
    $roles = array( get_role('shop_manager'), get_role('administrator') );

    /* Add the capabilities for each role */

    foreach($roles as $role) {
       if($role) {
          /* Add the primitive capabilities, e.g.: */
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_auftrag' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_auftrags' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_auftrags' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'publish_auftrags' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'read_auftrag' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'read_private_auftrag' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'delete_auftrag' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_auftrags' );
          $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_auftrags' );
       }
    }
}
```

**If the above doesn't work:**

1. The above is used in some of the questions on wordpress.stackexchange.com, although some don't set the capabilities array in the CPT... they only add the capabilities to roles (the 2nd block of code in this answer). If you have problems with the code above, try adding only the `add_produktionsauftrag_caps_role` function.
2. Even those those questions/answers do the above, the Codex says that meta capabilities *shouldn't* be assigned to any role, they must be mapped to corresponding primitive capabilities in `map_meta_cap()`.

Also, according to the codex:

> When some user have a role with just the post type capabilities it isn't enough for create new object... It's because meta capabilities for custom post types were not being automatically mapped, so we couldn’t have granular control over permissions. To map meta capabilities for custom post types we can use `map_meta_cap` hook as it's explain here : http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types.

... so even though the questions/answers on wordpress.stackexchange.com didn't use the `map_meta_cap`, you might need to.

References:

- [Codex
  register_post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#capability_type)
- [Meta capabilities for custom post
  types (justintadlock.com)](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types)
- [Wordpress capability_type
  arguments (wordpress.stackexchange.com)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59719/wordpress-capability-type-arguments)
- [Using Custom Meta Capabilities on Custom Post
  Type (wordpress.stackexchange.com)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120442/using-custom-meta-capabilities-on-custom-post-type)
- [The Ultimate Guide to Roles and Capabilities in WordPress (wpmayor.com)](https://www.wpmayor.com/roles-capabilities-wordpress/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried to get the read capability but couldnt get it with your help. I still just have a read_priveate_(postname) capability. I know sovled it with a javascript, its not a good solutions but its acutally all i have.

Comment: @Peesen87 I'm not sure you can even set meta capabilities through a plugin  (your screenshot looks like its using User Role Editor?). This answer should set the capabilities directly in the code, without the need of using a separate plugin so the `read` capabilities won't appear in the plugin :)